# How to replicate this chess-related list formatting?

Tags: formatting

I'm trying to create a chess-repeated document. I already understand how to use the skak package to put chess piece symbols in my documents. My current question is more pedestrian. I would like to replicate the list formatting in the picture at the end of this question (except with the page numbers replaced by more moves and personal notes). What is the best way to do this?

The only possibility I'm aware of is using a bunch of nested enumerate commands, but this seems very messy and would require me to tinker with the starting value for each one. I'm hoping someone more experienced can point me to a cleaner solution.

[image]
(from *How to Beat the Sicilian Defence* by Gawain Jones)

Comment: Maybe you can use the package [`tabto`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabto-generic)

Comment: It depends a lot on the number of levels you want maintain, and if the notes can be longer then one line, if you want to show diagrams, and what syntax you want to use.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Probably around a half-dozen levels, with notes longer than one line, but no diagrams needed. I'm looking for the cleanest and easiest to maintain syntax possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `tabbing`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{skak}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
A)2...d6\=3\symbishop b5+\symbishop\\
\>3...\symknight d7\=4d4\\
\>\>4...a6-23\\
\>\>4...\symknight f6\=50-0\\
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Comment: I think this is more complicated than an itemize environment.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel The OP was complaining about having to NEST itemised environments. Using `tabbing` avoids the need to have nested environments. (Also `\>` is shorter than `\item`...)